# How to get child element and attribute value with condition from xml data in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

How to get child value and its attribute value with condition in sql server.?
How to get this

```
<CheckoutAttribute ID="9">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>26</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
```

```
CheckoutAttributeID CheckoutAttributeValue
        9                    26
```

from following **xml** data.

```
<Attributes>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="4">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>18</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="6">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>22</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>23</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="9">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>26</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>27</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="1">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>1</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
</Attributes>
```

Comment: You sometimes have 2 checkout attribute values for each checkout attribute - do you want them on one row or 2? Please show the desired output for the whole of your sample input.

Comment: I want only one row for checkoutattribute id 9 with value 26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable ( id INT IDENTITY(1,1), xmlDataTest xml)
INSERT INTO #TempTable ( xmlDataTest)
VALUES ('<Attributes>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="4">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>18</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="6">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>22</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>23</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="9">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>26</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>27</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
<CheckoutAttribute ID="1">
<CheckoutAttributeValue><Value>1</Value></CheckoutAttributeValue>
</CheckoutAttribute>
</Attributes>')

SELECT r.value('@ID','int') AS CheckoutAttributeID
        , r.query('data(CheckoutAttributeValue/Value)[1]') AS CheckoutAttributeValue
FROM #tempTable
CROSS APPLY xmlDataTest.nodes('/Attributes/CheckoutAttribute') AS x(r)
WHERE
r.value('@ID','int') = 9 

DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

Comment: Hi manderson, in such cases its better to use `.nodes('/Attributes/CheckoutAttribute[@ID="9"]')` (or introduce this value with `sql:column() or sql:variable()`). Your solution has to read the whole lot, just to throw most of it away...